# Is it possible to attach Attachements to mailto app in windows 8 metro application?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, email-attachments

I am launching the mailto app in this way :-

```
 using Windows.System;
    //starts the default mail app with a subject, cc, bcc, and body
    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:windows8devs@almostbeta.com?subject=Code Request&cc=kevin@almostbeta.com&bcc=admin@almostbeta.com&body=Hi!"));
```

1) Can't we attach attachments to mailto app in windows 8?

2) If so please let me know what would be the work around ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't attach files to mail app in Windows 8.

You need to use Sharing. Take a look to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx, for an example on how to share files.

Comment: is it possible to set a subject to the mail app in windows 8 metro application , if i am using share contract and sharing files?